# Getting the eventargs of registered events

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm new to maps and OpenLayers, but I'm investigating Openlayers because I'll need map functionality in my next project. The map is a WMS image of a medieval town, but without any geo-referencing information.

I found how to register events, but the problem is that the "eventargs" is not working as in the examples I found. In one of the examples they are getting the x and y values after the users panned like this:

```
map.events.register('moveend', map, function (e)
{
    alert(e.xy);
});
```

If I try this in Visual Studio, e doesn't have an xy property. What am I missing? This is the code I have right now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">         

        var map, layer;

        function init() {
            var windowHeight = $(window).height();
            var windowWidth = $(window).width();
            var mapdiv = $('#map');
            mapdiv.css({width: windowWidth + 'px', height: windowHeight + 'px'});

            map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', { maxResolution: 1000 });
            layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Image(
               'Globe ESA',
               '[url]',
               new OpenLayers.Bounds(-180.0, -12333.5, 21755.5, 90.0),
               new OpenLayers.Size(windowWidth, windowHeight),
               {numZoomLevels: 100}
            );
            map.addLayer(layer);
            nav = new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation();
            map.addControl(nav);
            //events test
            map.events.register('moveend', map, function (e)
            {
                alert(e.xy);
            });
            map.zoomToMaxExtent();
        }
    </script>
```

In the OpenLayers examples they don't use the eventargs, but I assume that there must be a way to get the zoomlevel, or the x and y after panning?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no explicit xy sent to the moveend event as a parameter to the listener. So, while you can write,

```
map.events.register('moveend', map, function(xy){
```

xy won't contain any useful information.

However, you can get information from the OpenLayers.Map itself, such as maxExtent and zoom, which you are passing in as the object to the moveend event.

```
 map.events.register('moveend', map, function(){           
    console.log(map.maxExtent + " " + map.getZoom());
 });
```

There are many other properties associated with the map, which you can see if you set a breakpoint inside the moveend callback. If you haven't looked at the source for map, it is well worth it to understand what is going on. [OpenLayers.Map.js](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Map.js)

You will see that the moveend event is triggered either without any parameters or with one, a boolean, zoomChanged.

Comment: Thank you for your help! At least i know now that openlayers will not help me.

Comment: Well, you can get zoom and extents, which is what you asked for no? OpenLayers is an extremely well put together lib, imho, I basically learnt Javascript from ready the source code. You can pretty much do anything, if you are prepared to extend the functions.

Comment: Yes, but the exents never change. I can pan around as much as i want. I need to know how much, so i can ask a new image to the server with the knew bounds.

Comment: If you run, map.getExtent() on moveend, the extents ought to be different. Have you thought of using a WMS? OpenLayers is set up to handle tiled coverage automatically, so you don't have to worry about such things for yourself.

Comment: It is a wms, but it needs to return an image. It's not tiled. So through the wms i get an image of the map. It's a map, but drawn in the Middle ages. Coordinates etc don't exist here. So i think each time there is a padding or zoom, i need to ask for a new image.

Comment: Interesting problem. I love medieval maps, but have never tried on in OpenLayers :D Good luck.